# How do I solve emacs launcher icon failures?

Tags: launcher, emacs

I've just installed emacs 24 on 12.04 following the instructions here: http://www.mikeyboldt.com/2011/11/30...-24-in-ubuntu/ and though it installs and I can run it from the terminal, I can't get an icon for the app to work in the launcher. I.e. after the first launch, an icon does appear (and I was able to "lock" it in the launcher), but clicking on it doesn't switch me to emacs, nor does an emacs icon show up when switching between applications with alt-tab.

Also, after closing down the app, clicking on the icon that was put in the launchbar, doesn't actually launch emacs.

Where do I find error logs to diagnose this kind of problem?  Anybody had something similar happen?

Comment: i have this issue. there is a related bug that isn't seeing much love at the moment https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/704187

Comment: Well, I figured out that the problem sort of solved itself in that after logging out and logging back in again, a different and correct icon for emacs showed up in the launcher (called "Emacs Snapshot (GTK)").  But it doesn't really address the bug.  I did end up reporting the bug over on launchpad here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/993711  so if you have this problem you could add yourself to the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command:

```
sudo wget http://garethrees.org/2009/08/19/emacs23/emacs.svg -O /usr/share/icon/hicolor/scalable/apps/emacs23.svg
```